# C# Simulate DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, simulation

I want to simulate DateTime. Lets say I have list of actions to perform and each action has a datetime field. When that dateTime comes, the action should be performed. I can check the datetime with DateTime.Now; But how can I simulate DateTime. I mean If the current time is 2pm. And the action should run at 4pm, 5pm. Can I use a simulate current time to 4pm and the first action will be performed and an hour later the second action will be performed.

Thanks,

Comment: The time should continue from 4pm on its own. i.e. It should work like a clock.

Comment: You need to introduce datetime provider interface, a class that would pass the date to your class. And for testing purposes you need to implement a dummy version of that interface

Comment: I have actually Implement this using d Timespan value.
E.g. Lets say I want d system clock to be 01-May-2012 21:00:00PM. 
Current date is May 8th 11:38:00 PM. When d application starts I get d difference
DateTime simulateDateTime = '01-May-2012 21:00:00";
long ticksDifference = DateTime.Now.Subtract;
compare d date
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new Timespan(ticksDifference));
This gives me exactly what I need now. CurrentDateTime field works like a clock since DateTime.Now always changes 
& d difference with timespan gives me d accurate simulation clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to change your system clock to the 'test time', run the test, and then change back.  That's pretty hacky and I don't really recommend it, but it will work.

A better way will be to use an abstraction over `DateTime.Now` which will allow you to inject either a static value or manipulate the retrieved value for testing. Given that you want the test value to 'tick', rather than remain a static snapshot, it's going to be easiest to add a `TimeSpan` to 'now'.

So add a application setting called 'offset' that can be parsed as a `TimeSpan`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="offset" value="00:00:00" />
</appSettings>
```

and then add this value to your `DateTime.Now` every time you retrieve it.

```
public DateTime Time
{ 
    get 
    { 
        var offset = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["offset"]);
        return DateTime.Now + offset;
    }
}
```

To run this one hour and twenty minutes in the future you simply adjust the `offset` value

```
<add key="offset" value="01:20:00" />
```

Ideally you'd create an interface for a `DateTime` and implement dependency injection, but for your purpose - although that would be preferred - I suggest that the can of worms that this opens will create a world of confusion for you. This is simple and will work.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I posted something regarding a way of testing Dates that way:

http://ivowiblo.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/how-to-test-datetime-now/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a complex problem, but luckily there is a solution:  [Noda Time](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to comment out the part that checks DateTime.Now and create a new method/property which you can call which would return a scripted set of times.

For example:

```
class FakeDateTime
{
    private static int currentIndex = -1;
    private static DateTime[] testDateTimes = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2012,5,8,8,50,10),
            new DateTime(2012,5,8,8,50,10)  //List out the times you want to test here
        };

    /// <summary>
    /// The property to access to check the time.  This would replace DateTime.Now.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Now
    {
        get
        {
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % testDateTimes.Length;
            return testDateTimes[currentIndex];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this if you want to specifiy the time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeIndex">The index in <see cref="testDateTimes"/> you want to return.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public DateTime GetNow(int timeIndex)
    {
        return testDateTimes[timeIndex % testDateTimes.Length];
    }
}
```

If you would like a more specific (or better) answer please provide some code samples.